# Fatal error: Call to undefined function with strings

Tags: php

```
<?
  function generateRenStr($length) {
    $character = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $rendom_str = "";
    $loopNum = $length;
    while ($loopNum--) {
      $rendom_str .= $character(mt_rand(0, strlen($character)));
    }
    return $rendom_str;
  }
?>
```

When I run it, web browser says

> 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ() in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack\apache2\htdocs\loginmodule\lib\codegen.php on
>   line 7' 
> And
>   '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' is
>   NOT a function.

How can I fix it?

Comment: change this `$rendom_str .= $character(mt_rand(0, strlen($character)));` to this  `$rendom_str .= $character[mt_rand(0, strlen($character)-1)];`

Comment: Try this one https://eval.in/863937

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
while ($loopNum--) {
  $rendom_str .= $character(mt_rand(0, strlen($character)));
}
```

`$character` is a variable that stores a **string** and you're trying to access it as a function. Wrong brackets used **()**, you need **[]**.

Try this:

```
while ($loopNum--) {
  $rendom_str .= $character[mt_rand(0, strlen($character)-1)];
}
```